# Establishing whether a set is open or closed and bounded or unbounded

Tags: real-analysis

I am having trouble establishing whether the following set is open or closed and bounded or unbounded.

> $A=\{ \vec{x}=(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n: \: 1 \leq x_j^2 \leq 2, \: j=1,\dots,n \}$.

I started by saying that the boundary points of $A$ are $\vec{u}=\left(-\sqrt2,-\sqrt2,\dots,-\sqrt2\right) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\vec{v}=\left(\sqrt2,\sqrt2,\dots,\sqrt2\right) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and as $\vec{u},\vec{v} \in A$, $A$ is closed.

But I'm not sure if this is correct. As for the open or closed part, I'm not sure where to start. Some help would be great!

Comment: Are you given that ||**x**|| = $\sqrt {\sum x_i^2}$?  if so for **x**$\in A$, ||**x**|| < $\sqrt{\sum \sqrt2^2} = \sqrt {2n}$ so A is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

What you are saying is correct for some part, you can say that all boundary points of $A$ are inside $A$. The problem is that you are not listing all the boundary points. Try taking $n=2$ and draw $A$.

You can even start with $n=1$ and see that $x=1 $ and $x=-1 $  are boundary points of A too.

Comment: I see what you mean. Proving that all boundary points, $\vec{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, are within the set is proving to be quite tricky.

Comment: Yes, just simply because in n dimensions  you have an infinite amount of boundary points. You can just say that for all the boundary points there is an $x_j$ such that $x_j^2 =1$ or $x_j^2 =2 $.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to find boundary points. Just find solution to inequalities $1 \leq x^2 \leq 2$ and consider that finite (but also infinite) products of compact sets are compact too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some problems here.
First, your domain is bounded because if we take any element $x \in A$ then
$\parallel x \parallel_{\infty} \leq \sqrt{2}$. That is the good way to say it.

Your space isn't connected (try drawing it for n=2). Giving two boundary points wont be enough here. You have to show that your can put you space in a ball which has a finite radius.

To show that A is closed, you can prove that the cartesian products of two closed sets is closed and proceed by mathematical induction.

Comment: I understand, thank you. Unfortunately, we haven't studied cartesian products of sets in this particular course so I don't think I'd be able to use that.